# http redirection error 302 with odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, ubuntu-16.04, http-error

I use **odoo8 + postgresql9.4 on ubuntu16**. I restart Odoo service after                              the /etc/odoo/openerp-server.conf file editing to add the following parameter **unaccent = True**, then nothing works. I removed it but nothing happens.

So, i had try this one but in vain

I emptied the contents of /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log before restart Odoo(sudo systemctl restart odoo). I read the log file and obtained this following:

> 2016-11-03 03:10:39,989 6545 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Initiating
>   shutdown 2016-11-03 03:10:39,990 6545 INFO ? openerp.service.server:
>   Hit CTRL-C again or send a second signal to force the shutdown.
>   2016-11-03 03:10:40,654 6632 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version
>   8.0-20161102 2016-11-03 03:10:40,654 6632 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/var/lib/odoo/addons/8.0', u'/mnt/extra-addons',
>   u'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons'] 2016-11-03
>   03:10:40,654 6632 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
>   2016-11-03 03:10:40,655 6632 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
>   2016-11-03 03:10:40,655 6632 INFO ? openerp: database user: damby
>   2016-11-03 03:10:40,896 6632 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Watching
>   addons folder /var/lib/odoo/addons/8.0 2016-11-03 03:10:40,896 6632
>   INFO ? openerp.service.server: Watching addons folder
>   /mnt/extra-addons 2016-11-03 03:10:40,898 6632 INFO ?
>   openerp.service.server: Watching addons folder
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons 2016-11-03
>   03:10:41,128 6632 INFO ? openerp.service.server: AutoReload watcher
>   running 2016-11-03 03:10:41,128 6632 INFO ? openerp.service.server:
>   HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
>   2016-11-03 03:15:06,925 6632 INFO ?
>   openerp.addons.report.models.report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary
>   at /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf 2016-11-03 03:15:07,255 6632 INFO ?
>   openerp.http: HTTP Configuring static files 2016-11-03 03:15:07,266
>   6632 INFO cuisine openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
>   2016-11-03 03:15:07,276 6632 INFO cuisine openerp.modules.loading: 1
>   modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries 2016-11-03 03:15:07,284 6632 INFO
>   cuisine openerp.modules.loading: loading 13 modules... 2016-11-03
>   03:15:07,302 6632 INFO cuisine openerp.modules.loading: 13 modules
>   loaded in 0.02s, 0 queries 2016-11-03 03:15:07,516 6632 INFO cuisine
>   openerp.http: Generating nondb routing 2016-11-03 03:15:07,534 6632
>   INFO cuisine werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2016 03:15:07] "GET
>   /web?db=cuisine HTTP/1.1" 302 - 2016-11-03 03:15:07,543 6632 INFO
>   cuisine openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules... 2016-11-03
>   03:15:07,554 6632 INFO cuisine openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules
>   loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries 2016-11-03 03:15:07,561 6632 INFO cuisine
>   openerp.modules.loading: loading 13 modules... 2016-11-03 03:15:07,564
>   6632 INFO cuisine openerp.modules.loading: 13 modules loaded in 0.00s,
>   0 queries

And **Firefox Dev Edition 51** tell me " The page isn’t redirecting properly "
database name is **cuisine**

Answer (score 0):

[My odoo module cookbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFaOZ.png)

the file cookbook/models/recipe.py contains badly indented code.
I refered to https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle to solve my problem by applying **pycodestyle** to recipe.py like that:
damby@e6520:/mnt/extra-addons/cookbook/models$ **pycodestyle recipe.py**